# Convert Amazon AMI to local Xen machine

Tags: virtualization, amazon-ec2, xen, virtual-machines

I have an AMI which was created from a base AMI on Amazon. I would like to bring a copy of this internally to run for development. I have downloaded the .manifest & part00-50 files (approx 550mb) from my S3 bucket. Unsure how to convert into my local Xencenter however.

I have checked google, and nobody else seems to have tried this as yet. Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks- Alistair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .img file, from ec2-unbundle, is the file that typically uses extension .raw on some virtualization platforms - It's just the raw disk contents byte-for-byte.

Most virtualization software can use this .raw file as the disk - I haven't done much with XEN, but VirtualBox and QEMU will both use it fine - HyperV and Virtual Server will need it converted to VHD format. I would expect XEN to use it.

A quick google for xen and raw shows this may be the command (but a lot of useless posts came back so not sure):

disk = [ 'file:/home/xen/ec2image/ec2file.img,hda,w' ]

NOTE: You will likely have driver issues, you didn't say if this is windows, linux or other. It will likely detect new hardware.

LICENSES: If this is Windows you are going to have license issues (perhaps not technical but definately legally speaking).

Answer (score 2):

`ec2-unbundle`: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/dg/2006-10-01/CLTRG-ami-unbundle.html This is a raw disk image which is what Xen uses.

Comment: Still not sure exactly how this command works to convert into a Xen image that I can run on my local XenCenter?